# Calculating curve integral of infinit long wire the Mathematical way?

Tags: electromagnetism

In the script it's easily given $\int B\,\mathrm{ds} \quad$ where $B$ is the magnetic field of an infinite long wire: $$B(r) = \dfrac{\mu_0\,I}{2\,\pi\,r}$$ and $s$ is  a concentric circle around the wire with $s = 2\,\pi\,r$. Because $B$ and $s$ are perpendicular the integral just becomes:
$$\int B\,\mathrm{ds} = \mu_0\,I$$

I totally understand the approach intuitively but since I learned about the mathematical definition of curve integrals recently I tried to transmit it someway:

According to curve integral:
*let $X:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector field and $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow U$ a curve, then* $$\int_a^b\langle X(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle \,\mathrm{dt}$$
*is called the curve integral.*

But I fail to take use of that. As curve I'd chose $\gamma(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$ where $t \in[0,2\,\pi]$ but I can't produce the dot product because $B$ doesn't seem to be a vector valued function with 2 entries...

$\textbf{Add: To get a little more specific}$: let's suppose I've got straight wire positioned in the z axis so changes along the wire are represented by:  $$\mathrm{d}\,l= \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ \mathrm{d}l \end{array}\right)$$ Now let's consider the distance to a point around the wire: $$r =  
{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
Hence the magnetic field in this point (Biot-Savart-law):

$$\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{d}B = \dfrac{I\,\mu_0 }{4\,\pi \,\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3} \, \left(\begin{array}{c} x\\ y\\ z \end{array}\right) \times \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ \mathrm{d}l \end{array}\right) \\\\ \mathrm{d}B =  \dfrac{I\,\mu_0 }{4\,\pi \,\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3}\,\left(\begin{array}{cc} \mathrm{d}l\,y\\ -\mathrm{d}l\,x\\ 0 \end{array}\right)\end{array}$$

Now I'd introduce my parametrization of a circle around the wire:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\left(t\right)\\ \sin\left(t\right)\\ \mathrm{d}l \end{array}\right) \quad t \in [0, 2\,\pi]$$ So the integral becomes:

$$\begin{array}{cc}\displaystyle{\int_a^b\langle \mathrm{d}B(\gamma(t)),\gamma'(t)\rangle \,\mathrm{dt}} \\\\ = \displaystyle{\int_0^{2\,\pi}}\biggl\langle\frac{I\,\mu }{4\,\pi \,\sqrt{{\mathrm{dl}}^2+{\cos\left(t\right)}^2+{\sin\left(t\right)}^2}}\,\left(\begin{array}{c} \mathrm{d}l\,\sin\left(t\right)\\ -\mathrm{d}l\,\cos\left(t\right)\\ 0 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c} -\sin\left(t\right)\\ \cos\left(t\right)\\ 0 \end{array}\right)\biggr\rangle \,\mathrm{dt} \\\\ = \displaystyle{\int_0^{2\,\pi}-\frac{I\,\mathrm{dl}\,\mu \,{\cos\left(t\right)}^2}{4\,\pi \,\sqrt{{\mathrm{dl}}^2+{\cos\left(t\right)}^2+{\sin\left(t\right)}^2}}-\frac{I\,\mathrm{dl}\,\mu \,{\sin\left(t\right)}^2}{4\,\pi \,\sqrt{{\mathrm{dl}}^2+{\cos\left(t\right)}^2+{\sin\left(t\right)}^2}}}\,\mathrm{dt} \end{array}$$

what's not computable. So where was I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{B}$ is in fact a vector-valued function;  your equation for $B(r)$ just ignores it (or assumes it implicitly.)  Really, the field for a long wire will be
$$
\vec{B} = B(r) = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} \hat{\phi}
$$
where $\hat{\phi}$ is a unit vector pointing in the direction of increasing $\phi$.  In terms of Cartesian coordinates, this vector would be
$$
\hat{\phi} = (-y/r, x/r)
$$
where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$.  (This is not too hard to show by sketching out similar triangles.)

Based on this, and your parametrization of the curve, you should be able to show that $\oint \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{s} = \mu_0 I.$

**EDIT:**

You seem to be conflating two concepts:  integrals for Ampere's Law and integrals for the Biot-Savart Law.  The integration you're doing for Ampere's Law is an integral over some imaginary loop surrounding the wire;  it's not over the wire that produces the field.  In contrast, the Biot-Savart Law *is* actually an integral over the current sources.

In principle, you could use both of these in turn:

- Integrate $\mathrm{d}\vec{B}$ over the length of the wire to obtain the total magnetic field $\vec{B}$ at an arbitrary point.  This would involve integrating your (correct) expression for $\mathrm{d}\vec{B}$,
  $$
  \mathrm{d}B =  \dfrac{I\,\mu_0 }{4\,\pi \,\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3}\,\left(\begin{array}{cc} \mathrm{d}l\,y\\ -\mathrm{d}l\,x\\ 0 \end{array}\right)
  $$
  from $z = - \infty$ to $\infty$ (with $dl\to dz$, since we are integrating along the $z$-axis.)  Note that the resulting expression will not involve any $\mathrm{d}l$ quantities or the like;  all $z$-dependence in the result will drop out as well.
- Take your result from the previous integral and integrate $\vec{B}$ (not $\mathrm{d}\vec{B}$) along a circular loop surrounding the wire.  The parametrization you have is mostly correct, but you don't need the $\mathrm{d}l$ in it:
  $$
  \gamma(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\left(t\right)\\ \sin\left(t\right)\\ 0 \end{array}\right) \quad t \in [0, 2\,\pi]
  $$
  If you then integrate $\langle \vec{B}(\gamma(t)), \gamma'(t) \rangle$ from 0 to 2π, you should obtain the desired result.

Comment: May u take a look at my edits please?